# How to observe either of two events - shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have an interactive RMarkdown document like this:

````
---
title: "CLT"
author: "James"
date: "9/25/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# two input buttons
inputPanel(
 actionButton("go", "1 sample"),
 actionButton("go2", "20 samples")
)

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# population of data
pop1 <- rnorm(100000,10,2.5)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# get mean of one sample if button 1 pressed
Vals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    mean(sample(pop1, 10, T))
  })
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# get means of 20 samples if button 2 pressed
    Vals2 <- eventReactive(input$go2, {
     apply(replicate(20, sample(pop1, 10, T)),2,mean)
  })
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# count how many times button 1 is pressed
x <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    x(x() + 1)
  })

# add mean of one sample to a vector
  y <- reactiveVal(NA)

    observeEvent(input$go, {
    y(c(y(),Vals()))
  })


```
  
 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({
    x()
  })
```
  
```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({
    tail(y(),10)
  })
```
````

We have two button inputs.  One will lead to an `eventReactive()` event that calculates the mean of one sample.  The other leads to an `eventReactive()` event that calculates the means of 20 samples.

I wish to keep 1) a count of how many samples have occurred (every click of the 1 sample button should add 1 to the tally, and every click of the 20 sample button should add 20 to the tally).  I also am trying to update a vector `y()` through `observeEvent()` to store the means as we go.  I can get this working for just the one sample button, but not when I want to add the 20 sample button.

For instance, say I have clicked the one sample button 5 times, but now I click the 20 sample button, I would like the counter `x()` to now show 25, and `y()` should have 26 elements (I started it with NA in the first element position).

Is it possible to somehow have an either/or reactive with `observeEvent()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work according to your needs :

- x is increasing by 1 or 20
- y is storing the values

I used `NULL` instead of `NA` to initialize `y` so that the first element isn't empty.
I added a `print` which you can remove to verify the content of `y` in the console after each update (because you just output `tail(y(),10)`

````
---
title: "CLT"
author: "James"
date: "9/25/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
  
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# two input buttons
inputPanel(
  actionButton("go", "1 sample"),
  actionButton("go2", "20 samples")
)

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# population of data
pop1 <- rnorm(100000,10,2.5)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# get mean of one sample if button 1 pressed
Vals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  mean(sample(pop1, 10, T))
})
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# get means of 20 samples if button 2 pressed
Vals2 <- eventReactive(input$go2, {
  apply(replicate(20, sample(pop1, 10, T)),2,mean)
})
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# count how many times button 1 is pressed
x <- reactiveVal(0)
# add mean of one sample to a vector
y <- reactiveVal(NULL)

observeEvent(input$go, {
  x(x() + 1)
})

observeEvent(input$go2, {
  x(x() + 20)
})


observeEvent(input$go, {
  y(c(y(),Vals()))
})

observeEvent(input$go2, {
  print(y())
  y(c(y(),Vals2()))
})



```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({
  x()
})
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({
  tail(y(),10)
})
```
````

[image]